# `utf8_general_ci' is a collation of the deprecated character set UTF8MB3

Tags: mysql

```
/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
```

i am trying to use the code at the end of my program and i am getting warnings like
'utf8_general_ci' is a collation of the deprecated character set UTF8MB3. Please consider using UTF8MB4 with an appropriate collation instead.

'utf8' is currently an alias for the character set UTF8MB3, but will be an alias for UTF8MB4 in a future release. Please consider using UTF8MB4 in order to be unambiguous.

Can anybody help me in solving this...........

Answer (score 0):

> Because upgrading from earlier character-sets requires **tables to be rebuilt**, we expect that it may be some it time before we are able to move from deprecation to removal.

source https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-when-to-use-utf8mb3-over-utf8mb4/

you can try after a backup to alter the tables 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-unicode-conversion.html